# How to populate Adal8Service 's configOptions using config settings in Angular 7 and load when the application loads

Tags: angular7, config, adal

I am using `import { Adal8Service, Adal8HTTPService } from 'adal-angular8';` for Azure authentication. I am using the below in `app.module.ts`:

```
export function appInit(appConfigService: AppInitService) {
  return (): any => {
    appConfigService.getApplicationConfig().subscribe((res) =>{
      sessionStorage.setItem("appConfig",JSON.stringify(res));
      timeout(500);
    });
  }
}
```

my getApplicationConfig() is below:

```
public getApplicationConfig() {
    return this.http.get('assets/config.json');}
```

and in the `providers []` the below:

```
 AuthenticationService,
    AppInitService,
    {
      provide: APP_INITIALIZER,
      useFactory: appInit,
      deps: [AppInitService],
      multi: true
    },
    Adal8Service, 
    { provide: Adal8HTTPService, 
      useFactory: Adal8HTTPService.factory, 
      deps: [HttpClient, Adal8Service],
      multi: true 
    },
```

The here is the `appInit` function does not block (even removing the timeout()) the application loading and proceeds to to the 
`this.adalService.init(this.adalConfig);
 this.adalService.handleWindowCallback();` 
(where `this.adalConfig = sessionStorage.getItem("appConfig")`).

If I refresh the page, then I am getting redirected to the Azure Ad login page properly or if I am hardcoding the `configOptions` of the `this.adalService.init("HARDOCDE all values")` then it works fine. How do I make the application block the configuration. I am storing the config values under `/assets/config.json`. I am not sure what I am doing wrong here. I did try reading the "json" file, but again I have to change it before proceeding to production. How do I make the application wait, there are also other config values for the application stored in the `/assets/config.json` file. Is the way I use the APP_INITIALIZER correct? Please point me to right direction.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not related to ADAL but related to how asynchronous functions works in javascript. 
In order to block the execution of the function, you can either write down a function which waits till the response is returned by the http request or you can use library like [waitfor-ES6](https://github.com/luciotato/waitfor-ES6) which can help you do that.

Change needs to be done at

```
export function appInit(appConfigService: AppInitService) {
  return (): any => {
    response = yield wait.for(appConfigService.getApplicationConfig);
    sessionStorage.setItem("appConfig",JSON.stringify(response));
  }
}
```

Please note this is not exact change but the direction of the change that you will need to perform. Hope this helps.

Comment: I gave up and hard coded the values in the constructor, I think my issue is more of a logic rather than anything else. I kick off an AuthenticationService and then Adal8Service as indicated above, I was supposing that APP_INITIALIZER in AppInitService (above) will be executed first, I could not figure out a way in the time frame I have, unless someone has already done it. Thank you anyway. I am sure if I get a chance I will try your logic

Comment: Use the solution which I suggested, it would definitely work. The problem is due to async nature of javascript only. If this solves the problem, please upvote and accept the answer.